# Return nodes at a specific depth level of relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I'm interested in ONLY friends-of-friends who listen to a particular band (for examples sake), how would I filter out immediate friends who also listen to that band?

```
MATCH (u:User {ID:123})-[friend_rel:FRIENDS_WITH]-(fof:User)-[band_rel:LISTENS_TO]-(b:Band {ID:456}) 
RETURN u, friend_rel, fof, band_rel, b;
```

How do I filter down to all fof nodes in a FRIENDS_WITH relationship at depth of 2 only?

Answer (score 2):

`[friend_rel:FRIENDS_WITH*2]`

Edit: Use the keyword `DISTINCT` to avoid repetitions

For more info, look up variable length paths.